# get only image related with name logo

Tags: php

my regex is `$image_regex = '/<img[^>]*'.'src=[\"|\'](.*)[\"|\']/Ui';`

But I need a regular expression to check if it contains only the images name related with "logo" any idea friends.

Answer (score 1):

you can check strpos() function on image name which will tell you all the story.

```
$img = 'logo_image.png';
if (strpos($img,'logo') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
}
```

Comment: simply place this code between foreach loop of you array. like foreach($img_array as $img){ if (strpos($img,'logo') !== false) {
    echo 'true';
} }